# How to link 2 columns in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a list with a column task and a column weight
task = text
Weight= numbers
Each task as a specific weight, I want when someone select a task the weight field automatically is fill.

Best regards

Yves

Answer (score 0):

You can make weight as a calculated field with data return type as number when you create this column. Then in the formula field you can have something like `=IF([task]="Test",10,20)`. This will fill the weight column with 10 id task equals "test" or 20 otherwise.

You can refer this

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071%28v=office.14%29.aspx